# IIS7 Add New Website / Host Header ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

How can I either create a new website or add a host header to an existing IIS 7 server from code?

I have looked and have not been able to find a working example?

Comment: Can you try to explain a little bit more specifically what you are trying to do? "IIS7 Add New Website / Host Header ASP.NET Web Form" is just a bunch of key words.

Comment: i require to add a new website / hostheader within a asp.net web form application programatically.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a custom HttpModule that does the work for you, however it does require you to be have a DNS that supports wildcards (*).  If your DNS does not support that, you might look into managing your own DNS.

That said, here's a good post on creating an HttpModule that parses the "subdomain" passed in and forwards the traffic to the appropriate spot.  He's using a search mechanism [to locate content with keywords matching the subdomain], but it can be modified for you own needs.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2006/06/27/146875.aspx

[EDIT]
Another solution would be to find a DNS provider that offers a programmable DNS service, perhaps through a web service.  You would then programatically add a subdomain to that DNS when needed from your application.  That's a super simplified explanation, and doesn't take into account your business needs.  Personally I prefer the HttpModule option for adding subdomains within an application as it requires less modification of the server(s) involved.

Comment: This answer is assuming you're wanting to do subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .Net are you using?

If you are using .Net 3.0 or 3.5, and if you only need to configure IIS7 (not 6 or 5), check out the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace -- it should have everything you need.

If you are using an older version of .net, have a look at WMI.

I don't have any WMI code for IIS 7 (we have a setup for an intranet application, but it uses IIS 6-compatible WMI).  But, here's a link to a tool you can use for figuring out the WMI stuff: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en  It will actually generate c# (or vb.net) code for manipulating WMI.  For IIS 7, I think that the root WMI namespace is root\WebAdministration.

Also, have a look at this link, it might help [Get to Know the IIS 7.0 WMI Provider Using CIM Studio](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/265/get-to-know-the-iis7-wmi-provider-using-cim-studio/)